# Line breaks don't work on browser, but work on jsfiddle.net

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to code a small and simple form with css and html. The problem is that the line breaks (more specifically the `<br>` tags) have no effect on my web page. When I load the page on the browser, every input and label seems to go in the same line. But when I run my code snippet on Jsfiddle.net it works just as it should. I have tried putting display:block in the style tag and it has no effect. I have also tried putting each input and label element inside a separated div and also no effect. I am using Chrome version 49.0. It doesn't work with Firefox as well.

Here is my CSS and HTML code

```css
body{
 background-color:white;
 color:black;
 margin:0px;
 border:0px;
 padding:20px;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing:3px;
}
#container{
 max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<form action="websitelista.txt" method="post" >
<label for="firstname"><strong><span>First Name</span></strong></label>
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" required>
<br>
<br>
<label for="secondname"><strong><span>Second Name</span></strong></label>
<input id="secondname" type="text" name="secondname" required>
<br>
<br>
<label for="email"><strong><span>Enter Your Email</span></strong></label>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
<br>
<br>
<label for="dateofbirth"><strong><span>Enter Your Birth Date</span></strong></label>
<input id="dateofbirth" type="date" name="dateofbirth" required>
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked><strong>Male</strong>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><strong>Female</strong>
<br>
<br>
<label for="tel"><strong><span>Enter Your Phone Number</span></strong></label>
<input id="tel" type="tel" name="phonenumber" required>
<br>
<br>
<p><strong>Do you wish for us to send emails about updates on our site and upcoming events?</strong></p>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="yes" checked><strong>Yes, Ido</strong>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="nope"><strong>No, I don't</strong>
<br>
<br>
<button id="buttonsend" type="submit">
</button>
<button id="buttonreset" type="reset" onclick="alert('All your data has been reset')"">
</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: That's weird. If I add this little css `#container label { display: block; }` it works just fine in Safari, Chrome(Version 53.0.2785.143) and Firefox.
But as you said you've already tried this.
Are you using any frameworks or anything similar? Because your code looks good.

Comment: Hey D. Mllr I have already tried that. This problem is driving me crazy. Here is how it looks like on Chrome(same on Mozilla): [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img924/4740/W9eH6V.png). I am not using any frameworks or anything similar. Just pure CSS. I am also using Sublime Text editor for coding.

Comment: To fix your problem I might need your whole code. If you want to share it just send me a GoogleDrive link or something. Then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Google Drive Link: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dx1Sdgu_HcWU5VeGtnV2JNYk0)

Comment: Thanks for providing your code! I've added an answer as well. But the answers of the other users are good attempts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it!

```html
<body>
<div id="container">
<form action="websitelista.txt" method="post" >
  <div>
    <label for="firstname"><strong><span>First Name</span></strong></label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <label for="secondname"><strong><span>Second Name</span></strong></label>
    <input id="secondname" type="text" name="secondname" required>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <label for="email"><strong><span>Enter Your Email</span></strong></label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <br/>
  <div>
    <label for="dateofbirth"><strong><span>Enter Your Birth Date</span></strong></label>
    <input id="dateofbirth" type="date" name="dateofbirth" required>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked><strong>Male</strong>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><strong>Female</strong>
  </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  <div>
    <label for="tel"><strong><span>Enter Your Phone Number</span></strong></label>
    <input id="tel" type="tel" name="phonenumber" required>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <p>
    <strong>Do you wish for us to send emails about updates on our site and upcoming events?
    </strong>
  </p>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="yes" checked><strong>Yes, Ido</strong>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="nope"><strong>No, I don't</strong>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <button id="buttonsend" type="submit"> 
    Submit 1
    </button>
    <button id="buttonreset" type="reset" onclick="alert('All your data has been reset')">
     Submit 1
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can try it with wrapping input & label into DIV. I am creating a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you have proivded in the comments as to your code source file there are no `<br />` tags occuring. If you had a `<br />` tag after each element you need separated it should work. The revised file is included below.

```
<body>
  <form action="websitelista.txt" method="post" >
<!--<label for="identification"><strong><span id="tab">Your Identification:</span></strong></label>
<input id="identification" type="numbers" name="id" placeholder="000"  required>-->
<label for="firstname"><strong><span>First Name</span></strong></label><br />
<input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" required><br />
<label for="secondname"><strong><span>Second Name</span></strong></label><br />
<input id="secondname" type="text" name="secondname" required><br />
<label for="email"><strong><span>Enter Your Email</span></strong></label><br />
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" required><br />
<label for="dateofbirth"><strong><span>Enter Your Birth Date</span></strong></label><br />
<input id="dateofbirth" type="date" name="dateofbirth" required><br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked><strong>Male</strong><br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"><strong>Female</strong><br />
<label for="tel"><strong><span>Enter Your Phone Number</span></strong></label><br />
<input id="tel" type="tel" name="phonenumber" required><br />
<p><strong>Do you wish for us to send emails about updates on our site and upcoming events?</strong></p><br />
<input type="radio" name="option" value="yes" checked><strong>Yes, Ido</strong>
<input type="radio" name="option" value="nope"><strong>No, I don't</strong><br />
<select id="countries" name="countries">
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
  <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
  <option value="AO">Angola</option>
  <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
  <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
  <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="AT">Austria</option>
  <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
  <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
  <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
  <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
  <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
  <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
  <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
  <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
  <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
  <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
  <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
  <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
  <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
  <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
  <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
  <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
  <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
  <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
  <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
  <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
  <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
  <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
  <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
  <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
  <option value="CA">Canada</option>
  <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
  <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
  <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
  <option value="TD">Chad</option>
  <option value="CL">Chile</option>
  <option value="CN">China</option>
  <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
  <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
  <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
  <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
  <option value="CG">Congo</option>
  <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
  <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
  <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
  <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
  <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
  <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
  <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
  <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
  <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
  <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
  <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
  <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
  <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
  <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
  <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
  <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
  <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
  <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
  <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
  <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
  <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
  <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
  <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
  <option value="FI">Finland</option>
  <option value="FR">France</option>
  <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
  <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
  <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
  <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
  <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
  <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
  <option value="DE">Germany</option>
  <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
  <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
  <option value="GR">Greece</option>
  <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
  <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
  <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
  <option value="GU">Guam</option>
  <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
  <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
  <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
  <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
  <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
  <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
  <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
  <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
  <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
  <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
  <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
  <option value="IN">India</option>
  <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
  <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
  <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
  <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
  <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
  <option value="IL">Israel</option>
  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
  <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
  <option value="JP">Japan</option>
  <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
  <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
  <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
  <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
  <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
  <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
  <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
  <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
  <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
  <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
  <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
  <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
  <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
  <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
  <option value="LY">Libya</option>
  <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
  <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
  <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
  <option value="MO">Macao</option>
  <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
  <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
  <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
  <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
  <option value="ML">Mali</option>
  <option value="MT">Malta</option>
  <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
  <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
  <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
  <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
  <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
  <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
  <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
  <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
  <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
  <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
  <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
  <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
  <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
  <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
  <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
  <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
  <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
  <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
  <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
  <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
  <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
  <option value="NE">Niger</option>
  <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
  <option value="NU">Niue</option>
  <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
  <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
  <option value="NO">Norway</option>
  <option value="OM">Oman</option>
  <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
  <option value="PW">Palau</option>
  <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
  <option value="PA">Panama</option>
  <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
  <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
  <option value="PE">Peru</option>
  <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
  <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
  <option value="PL">Poland</option>
  <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
  <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
  <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
  <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
  <option value="RO">Romania</option>
  <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
  <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
  <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
  <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
  <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
  <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
  <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
  <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
  <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
  <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
  <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
  <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
  <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
  <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
  <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
  <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
  <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
  <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
  <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
  <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
  <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
  <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
  <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
  <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
  <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
  <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
  <option value="ES">Spain</option>
  <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
  <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
  <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
  <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
  <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
  <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
  <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
  <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
  <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
  <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
  <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
  <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
  <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
  <option value="TG">Togo</option>
  <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
  <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
  <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
  <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
  <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
  <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
  <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
  <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
  <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
  <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
  <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
  <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="US">United States</option>
  <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
  <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
  <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
  <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
  <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
  <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
  <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
  <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
  <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
  <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
  <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
  <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<br />
<button id="buttonsend" type="submit">
  <button id="buttonreset" type="reset" onclick="alert('All your data has been reset')"">
  </button>
</form>
</body>
```